Creating an extruded circle at the center line of a mirror modifier
I'm trying to make an extruded circle at the center line of the mirror modifier, however it creates a center line that causes pinching and mess up the circular shape when extruded, how to better create the extruded circle shape at the mirror modifier line?
What I tried:
1- I beveled the vertex I want to convert to a circle for extrusion
2- I inset the created circular shape
3- Extruded the circle, however there's an artifact/pinching line at the edge of the mirror modifier center line
4- I tried dissolving edges but it seems it cant be done because this is the center line of the mirror modifier
I apparently can not delete that line which makes it just a hole, and I'm uncertain how can I better create an extruded circle at this mirror modifier center line?
Appreciate any solution idea
Update 1: Blend file uploaded, added picture showing object and modifiers






Please share your Blend file.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Did you enable the merge option of the Mirror modifier ? Did you try moving the edge down (the one where there is pinching ?

Also make sure there isn't an internal face down the middle of the mirror modifier.

I have updated the post with blend file,

Clipping is enabled for the mirror modifier, also I have checked if there's any duplicate face(s)/vertices and there wasn't

Put the Mirror modifier above the Subdivision Surface modifier, otherwise the mirror will take the virtual topology into account. Result:

